# redbeanphp как поменять значение в базе данных

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Как заменить значение balance, в таблице users, зная только email?

Comment: `UPDATE users SET balance=10 WHERE email=email@mail.ru` вот вам sql запрос , в redbeen уже сами переведете. Вот тут можете посмотреть https://obninsksite.ru/blog/php-scripts/lesson-redbeanphp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов. 
Первый - это свободный запрос через `exec`.
В данном случае это будет выглядеть так:

```php
<?php

require 'rb/rb-mysql.php';

R::setup('mysql:host=;dbname=', '','');
if ( !R::testConnection() )
{
    exit ('Нет соединения с базой данных');
}

$email = 'Admin@gmail.com'; // Email по которому ищем

R::exec("UPDATE `users` SET balance='testbalance' WHERE `email` = ?", ["$email"]);
```

Если значение в переменной - добавляете ещё один `?` и вносите переменную в массив после запятой.

Второй вариант - это получить сначала `id` записи с таким `email` в таблице

```
$email = 'Admin@gmail.com';
$send = R::find('users', 'email = ?', [$email]);
```

И в дальнейшем менять по ней.

```
$id = 1; // Загружаем объект с ID = 1
$send = R::load('users', $id);
$send->balance = "testbalance1";
R::store($send);
```